# Overlapping axes in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I created 2 axes for plotting live EEG signals from a device. And I'm getting 2 signals, one is eegBuffer and another one is FFT.

Here is the code:

```
 if eegCounter == 44         
            if plot1

             axes;   
             %subplot(2,1,1);
             time = 0:1/fse:secBuffer-1/fse;
             h1 = plot(time,eegBuffer);
             legend(eegName, 'Location','EastOutside');
             xlabel('Time (s)')
             ylabel('Voltage (uV)')        

             %subplot(3,1,2);
             %time = 0:1/fsa:secBuffer-1/fsa;
             %h2= plot(time,accBuffer);
             %xlabel('Time (s)')
             %ylabel('Acceleration (mG)')
             %legend(h2, accName, 'Location','EastOutside');

             %legend(h2, accName, 'Location','EastOutside');

             %This code deals with fft calculations

            %w = axis;
            %subplot(2,1,2);
            %Fse = 220;
            %T = 1/Fse;
            %time = 0:1/fse:secBuffer-1/fse;
            %x = eegCounter;
            %y = eegBuffer;
            %NFFT = 2^nextpow2(eegCounter);
            %Y = fft(y,NFFT)/eegCounter;
            %f = Fse/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
            %xlabel = ('frequency(Hz)');
            %ylabel = ('|y(f)|');
            %h2 = plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1)));

            plot1 = false;

            else
             cell1 = (num2cell(eegBuffer,1))';
             set(h1,{'ydata'},cell1);
             %cell2 = (num2cell(accBuffer,1))';
             %set(h2,{'ydata'},cell2);
             %cell3 = (num2cell(final,1))'; 
             %set(h3,{'ydata'},cell3);
            end

            axes;
            %subplot(2,1,2);
            Fse = 220;
            T = 1/Fse;
            time = 0:1/fse:secBuffer-1/fse;
            x = eegCounter;
            y = eegBuffer;
            NFFT = 2^nextpow2(eegCounter);
            Y = fft(y,NFFT)/eegCounter;
            f = Fse/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
            xlabel = ('frequency(Hz)');
            ylabel = ('|y(f)|');
            h2 = plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1)));


            plot2 = false;

            %plot3 = false;



        drawnow;   
        eegCounter = 0;
        end % if eegCounter
```

Since I'm getting 2 live signals, I'm using 2 axes to plot those 2 live signals. However those axes get overlapped. Here is the screen shot:
[image: screen shot]

You can clearly see that 2 axes are overlapping. How can I fix it?

Comment: So, you are plotting 2 axes in top of the other and your problem is that you are plotting 2 axes in top of the other? Im confused. What is what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to plot one axes on top and another axes under first axes

Comment: What do you mean "under"? Both together but without overlapping labels, or one full plot top another bottom? Can you shows us an example of what you want to get?

Comment: Please check this link: http://goo.gl/A4mPhM

Comment: Well, then you just need to uncomment the lines that  say subplot(2,1,1) subplot(2,1,2). Those are the ones that define the 2 plots. See the documentation for more info.

Comment: Okay, I did that and I got 2 different plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create subplots, you need to use the `subplot` (yeah, Im a bit redundant) function.

You need to call it for each subplot in the following way:

```
subplot( No. of subplot rows , No. of subplot columns, subplot number)
```

Therefore if you want to plot 2 things, one in top of the other, you need to call it:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
% plot you rthings
subplot(2,1,2)
%plot your second things
```

See [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) for more information